# How to list the content of a zip file within another zip file without extraction

Tags: linux, unix

We have a zip file which contains another zip file.
We tried zip -l file on a zip file but we don't know how to list the content of the other zip file within it, without any zip extraction.

Is that possible with Linux zip ?

Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You can view the directory of a ZIP file, but the only way to see the contents of a zipped ZIP file is to extract it first. Maybe only in memory, but you'll have to extract the zipped ZIP first.

(I can image you could write a tool that only partially unzips the zipped ZIP until it has the directory, but have never seen one.)