# Is it possible to recursively list zip file contents with 7 zip without extracting

Tags: command-line, compression, zip, 7-zip

Similar to this question I have a very large zip file which contains other zip files, folders, and files. I want to use 7-zip to extract a list of file names from it, recursing into subfolders and zip files. 7z l -r is a good start but doesn't recurse into zip files. Questions below come close, but it sounds like this is not possible.

[Read the contents of a zipped file without extraction?](https://superuser.com/questions/462788/read-the-contents-of-a-zipped-file-without-extraction)
[How to list the content of a zip file within another zip file without extraction](https://superuser.com/questions/569782/how-to-list-the-content-of-a-zip-file-within-another-zip-file-without-extraction)

I am on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Although it may be possible to extract the embedded archive to stdout and examine it from there. But probably not.